# How to fix Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I am trying to create a new build of an old react native project I created a month ago but I am getting this error

This app uses **Google Maps API** to work. It was working fine when I built it a month ago and was able to create a signed apk. But now I have to change the API key because old one is not working and need to create a new build. I did not made any changes to the code. I just changed the API key in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vas">
      <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <!-- Other tags -->

      <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'vas'
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')

include ':app'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
// other stuff
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps'))
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"){
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1"){
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1"){
        force = true
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
}
// other stuff
```

The build should work fine as it worked before and I never made any changes to any other file except `AndroidManifest.xml` but I get this error:

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>
> D8: Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1

I have already tried every possible solution I could find on **stackoverflow** and **github** but none of them worked. This is my final year project and I really can't figure out what is the problem.